# Algorithm used by mironsets

Tags: matlab, audio

I was curious to know which algorithm(stepwise) is used by the mironsets function of the MIRToolbox library to find the onsets in the audio signal. I am talking about the default functionality when we use mironsets.

Example:
o = mironsets('audio.wav')

Here o is the output onset strength envelope and looks like this[image]

There are some questions like - Where is the negative part of the signal gone? Why not all local maximas are considered as onsets?

Comment: You can take a look into the MIRToolbox [manual](https://www.jyu.fi/hum/laitokset/musiikki/en/research/coe/materials/mirtoolbox/MIRtoolbox1.5Guide) p. 88. Not all local maximas considered as onsets to avoid an overdetection. This is caused typically by an adaptive threshold, e. g. the median $m$ is computed in the enviroment and the condition is $y[n] > b + c\,m$, where $b$ is the base threshold and $c$ is a weighting factor. To the negative part of the signal: If mironsets takes the envelope as the onset curve, the enevelope can be simple computed by takting the abs. values of the signal.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I still could not find the details of the median in the manual. Where did you find it?

Comment: @Vertex could you please let me know?

Comment: I told you only one possible explanation for this phenomenon. I don't took this out of the manual :) As the manual's flow chart tolds, `mirpeaks` is called for finding peaks. See at p. 65. Take a look on the _Contrast_ parameter: a local maximum is only considered as a peak, if the amplitudes diff. to the previous and successor local maxima are higher than a given threshold.